# Сортировка по вычисляемым данным yii2

Tags: php, yii2, сортировка

в модели прописал геттер количества объявлений

```
 public function getAdscount()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ads::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])->where('name<>"tmp"')->count();
}
```

как реализовать сортировку по этому полю в gridview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782754 посмотрите ответ на такой же вопрос в этой теме